# Find whether jQuery object is included inside another jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

so let's say I have some jQuery that runs as follows:

```
var myVar1 = $('.myClass1, .myClass2');
myFunction(myVar1); // Does something to element myVar1

var myVar2 = $('#myId').parent();
myFunction(myVar2); // Does something to element myVar2
```

Here's the problem. Sometimes `#myId`'s parent will be its own element, but it will sometimes also have either class `.myClass1` or `.myClass2`. However, I don't want to run `myFunction()` on `#myId`'s parent twice.

So the html could either be like:

```
<div class="myClass1"></div>
<div class="myClass1"></div>
<div class="myClass2"></div>
<div>    
    <div id="myId"></div>
</div>
```

Or it could be like this:

```
<div class="myClass1">
    <div id="myId"></div>
</div>
<div class="myClass1"></div>
<div class="myClass2"></div>
```

The jQuery needs to call the function on each `<div>` only once.

How do I detect if `myVar2` is contained within `myVar1`?

Comment: Can you add some simple HTML illustrating an element you don't want selected?

Comment: I think your variables are misnamed. Shouldn't `one` and `two` be `myVar1` and `myVar2`?

Comment: I fixed the variable names.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote you,

> How do I detect if myVar2 is contained within myVar1?

Each of your variables is returning a jQuery object, which is great, sure. If you want to find out if one jQuery object contains yet another jQuery object in its returned set, you can [use jQuery's `index()` method.](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

From `index()`:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

So we know we can reasonably get a number equal to or greater than zero representing the index of this other jQuery object IF it exists inside of `myVar1`, otherwise we get -1 if it doesn't exist.

if `var myVar2 = $('#myId').parent();` is included in `var myVar1 = $('.myClass1, .myClass2')`, then running `myVar1.index(myVar2)` will return a number greater than or equal to zero. Otherwise -1.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [jQuery `not` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not/), which removes matched elements from the set. To modify your example:

```
var one = $('.myClass1, .myClass2');
myFunction(one); // Does something to element myVar1

var two = $('#myId').not(one).parent();
myFunction(two); // Does something to element myVar2
```

This modification to the second selection will make it so that `#myId` is selected only if the element does **not** have either the `.myClass1` or `.myClass2` class attached.

Comment: According to the documentation you can pass a jQuery object to not like this: `var two = $('#myId').not(one).parent();`

Comment: @JasonSperske Thanks, I didn't know about that, and it simplifies the code a bit further!

Comment: I think the final code might need a little more adjusting, now that I see the example html, just trying to come up with a jsfiddle to demonstrate this and I'm hitting a bit of a wall

Comment: @JasonSperske You're right, the example HTML kind of contradicts the explanation that was posted earlier.